# two foreign keys in one django model

Tags: python, api, django

I'm working on a project the scenario: teacher model then is the teacher has not a profile the institute which working at will upload the courses does this is written the way I have tried in the course model?

```
class Course(models.Model):
   course_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   student = models.ManyToMany(Student)
   institute_name = models.ForeignKey(Institute,on_delete=models.CASCADE , null=True,blank=True)
   teacher_name = models.ForeignKey(Teacher ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
   tags = models.ManyToManyField(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Then define:

```
if user loggedin in  user.is_institute
```

So querying in an institute like this:

```
if loggedin in user.is_teacher
```

And then will work on the teacher model. Does this structure fine?

I've heard `generic foreign keys` but I'm not sure if it working with API!?

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


Teacher, Institute have different fields name
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi. I'm familiar with Django and would love to help here, but I don't quite understand the question. Could you make the following changes? Anything in code blocks should be valid Python Code, so we're sure what your code is and what is part of your question. (For example, ``if user loggedin in user.is_institute`` is not valid code, both the syntax is broken and ``is_institute`` is never defined.) Also, if possible, please make the English clearer or get a friend to help you edit this question, I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do and where you are struggling. Thanks!